# putc skips an index putchar does not?

Tags: c

I have an a method that reads input and prints ascii characters to a file stream.

Originally it didn't need to print to a file so I used putchar and it worked fine
but now that I use putc or fputc it prints every other input.

Example:

input = test

Output = t s

```
    int readFile(char* input,FILE* inputFile)
{
    int anyChanges = 1;
    int iochar = 0;
    int i = 0;

    //credit Foster Chapter 2
    while (( iochar = getc(inputFile) ) != EOF )
    {
        //Returns 1 if no changes made, return 0 if any changes have been made.
        // printf("\t character --> %c",iochar);
        //printf("\nGot to first while loop\n");

        if(iochar != '\n')
        {
            // printf("Got to second loop\n");
            int printedColumns =0;
            input[i] = iochar;
            printf("input array ---> %c\n",input[i]);
            i++;
            printf("i:%d\n",i);
            printf("iochar:%d\n",iochar);
            //This if statement checks for normal ascii characters.
            //If the output is less than 72 it prints it and increments printedColumns.
            if (( ' ' <= iochar ) && ( iochar <= 126 ) )
            {
                fputc(input[i],inputFile);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you reading and writing to same file. Is it intended behaviour?

Comment: What is the content of the file ? What output do you get and what output do you expect ?

Comment: input is stdin if no filename is found.

Comment: content is text file with printable and non-printable ascii chars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here for getc & putc you are using same Stream pointr i.e. inputFile , you want to read and write onto same file ??

Comment: I am testing it with stdin and want to print to stdout. inputFile = stdin.

Comment: Oh, I see, I need to change to stdout.

Answer (score 0):

did you mean to fputc iochar instead of input[i] (since you already incremented i)?

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fputc/ states that the position indicator is incremented.